# Boolean modifier applies weirdly

Tags: modifiers

I am following [IanHubert's post-apocalyptic buildings tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNba2oEij2c) and I can't figure out why my boolean modifier takes so long to render, and why is it buggy.

[image: Original]

[image: Results]

As you can see, the mesh isn't edited, but the parts of the mesh overlapped by the boolean operand aren't displayed.

My building is made out of several stretched out cubes, joined togehter using <kbd>CTRL+J</kbd>. Blender freezes for about 30 seconds each time I swicth to edit or object mode or I try to move the operand or the object.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Hello, have you tried to set the operation to "Fast" instead of "Exact" in the modifier ?

Comment: No, I tried it and it works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Sorry for that stupid question, I'm still pretty new at Blender

Comment: It's not stupid at all ! The exact mode is using way heavier calculations to handle most of the cases which can cause artifacts, but in your case I thought it might be better to use the regular mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can use the "Fast" mode in the modifier settings in order to limit the heavy calculations caused by the "Exact" solver mode.